# Android: why my the text in textview is messing

Tags: android, textview

I have several textviews in my application, sometimes it looks messing, like below:

[image]

In normal case, it shoule be like this:

[image]

Anyone met this before? Thanks:)

Comment: Post your xml file pls

Comment: may be you are defining width of textview manually in your xml file which is insufficient for the text, you should use wrap_content for width of that TextView

Comment: not this case, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seemed the customized ROM made some changes to the framework, and the textview buffer is not well cleared before set the new text.
I solve this by setting empty text before setting the real text.

By the way, why my post got the minus point....